# What's the best way to transfer data between iOS and MacOS via wireless?

Tags: ios, objective-c, wifi, core-bluetooth

I want to transfer data directly between iOS and Mac(short distance) via bluetooth or Wi-fi.

I read some question and if we use bluetooth, we must add Bluetooth LE adapter and I don't want it.

If we use Wi-fi, that will effect on current Internet network.

What's the best and fastest way? I just want to send small data directly.
Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into Apple's Bonjour technology: [Bonjour Tutorial](http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-networking-and-bonjour-on-iphone/)

It might take a lot of work off the table, from discovering what other computers / devices are nearby to getting their IP Addy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [NSStream](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSStream_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or this third party [Library](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket) and Tcp protocol. You can use Bonjour to help in network devices discovery.  Both of the links above have samples applications.  Note:  both devices needed to be on the same lcal network.